# XSL: Group parent attributes using matching child attribute

Tags: xml, excel, xslt, grouping

Hey guys I'm trying to use transform an XML document to output a table directly into excel. The problem I'm having is I need to group elements by a child node. My current XSLT is this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="ScanData">
  <html>
  <body>
  <xsl:for-each select="Report/ReportHost">
    <xsl:if test="ReportItem/@severity &gt; 0">
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></h2><br/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:for-each select="ReportItem">
        <xsl:sort select = "@severity" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:sort select = "@pluginID"/>
    <xsl:if test="@severity &gt; 0">
    <xsl:if test="(preceding-sibling::*[1]/@pluginName != @pluginName)">
    <b>Severity: </b><xsl:value-of select="@severity"/><br/>
    <b>Name: </b><xsl:value-of select="@pluginName"/><br/>  
    <b>Synopsis: </b><xsl:value-of select="synopsis"/><br/> 
    <b>Description: </b><xsl:value-of select="description"/><br/>   
    <b>Solution: </b><xsl:value-of select="solution"/><br/> 
    </xsl:if>
    Port:<xsl:value-of select="@protocol"/>/<xsl:value-of select="@port"/><br/>
    </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Internal.xsl"?>
    <ScanData>
        <Report name="Report">
            <ReportHost name="192.168.1.1">      
                <ReportItem port="0" svc_name="general" protocol="tcp" severity="1" pluginID="11936" pluginName="OS Identification" pluginFamily="General">
                    <description>Using a combination of remote probes (TCP/IP, SMB, HTTP, NTP, SNMP, etc...), it is possible to guess the name of the remote operating system in use. It is also sometimes possible to guess the version of the operating system.</description>
                    <fname>os_fingerprint.nasl</fname>
                    <plugin_modification_date>2014/02/19</plugin_modification_date>
                    <plugin_name>OS Identification</plugin_name>
                    <plugin_publication_date>2003/12/09</plugin_publication_date>
                    <plugin_type>combined</plugin_type>
                    <risk_factor>None</risk_factor>
                    <script_version>$Revision: 2.37 $</script_version>
                    <solution>n/a</solution>
                    <synopsis>It is possible to guess the remote operating system.</synopsis>

                </ReportItem>
.....(ReportItem and ReportHost repeat with different findings and hosts)
```

The problem I have is that all the data is outputted per host address, but I need the data to be grouped by pluginID so instead of having "Host with these findings" I need "Findings with these hosts".
i.e.:
Current:
**ReportHost/@name**
*Finding Attributes (Name, Description, etc)*
*Affected Port*
*Affected Port*
*Affected Port*
*Finding Attributes (Name, Description, etc)*
*Affected Port*

**ReportHost/@name**
*Finding Attributes (Name, Description, etc)*
*Affected Port*
*Affected Port*
.
.
.

Required:
**Finding Attributes (Name, Description, etc)**
**ReportHost/@name**
*Affected Port*
*Affected Port*
*Affected Port*
**ReportHost/@name**
*Affected Port*

**Finding Attributes (Name, Description, etc)**
**ReportHost/@name**
*Affected Port*
*Affected Port*
.
.

I know I said I need it in excel, and I have already made a workable XSL for excel I'm just using HTML for the convenience of testing (no tools just notepad++ and Firefox). Sorry if I didn't explain very well. I think I need to use Muenchian Grouping as for-each-group is not permitted in excel, but I'm a XML noob and I cant seem to get my head around it.

Thanks in advance.

James

Comment: Would it be possible to amend your question to show a slightly bigger XML sample. One that shows `ReportItem` elements belonging to differing hosts/plugs! You can probably cut down on the size though, by removing some of the fields within the `ReportItem` element. Also, it then might be a good idea to show the actual output expected for that sample. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do indeed need Muenchian Grouping here. Infact, you need to use it twice. Firstly you are grouping `ReportItem` elements by plugin, so you define a key like so (Note I have included the condition on severity because it looks from your existing XSLT you only want items with a non-zero severity)

```
<xsl:key name="plugin" match="ReportItem[@severity > 0]" use="@pluginID" />
```

By within this "group" of plugins you then need to group them by the `ReportHost`. To do this, you define a second key, but because it is a "group-within-a-group" you still need to reference the plugin id:

```
<xsl:key name="plugin_by_report" match="ReportItem[@severity > 0]" use="concat(@pluginID, '|', ../@name)" />
```

Note the use of `..` to get the parent `ReportHost` element here

Then, to get the distinct plugins, you use the first key

And within this group, to get the distinct items by `ReportHost`, you do this

```
<xsl:for-each 
     select="key('plugin', @pluginID)
             [generate-id() = generate-id(key('plugin_by_report',concat(@pluginID, '|', ../@name))[1])]">
```

Try this XSL for starters:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="plugin" match="ReportItem[@severity > 0]" use="@pluginID" />
<xsl:key name="plugin_by_report" match="ReportItem[@severity > 0]" use="concat(@pluginID, '|', ../@name)" />

<xsl:template match="ScanData">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="Report/ReportHost/ReportItem[generate-id() = generate-id(key('plugin', @pluginID)[1])]">
                <h2>Plugin: <xsl:value-of select="@pluginName"/></h2>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('plugin', @pluginID)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('plugin_by_report',concat(@pluginID, '|', ../@name))[1])]">
                    <h3>Host: <xsl:value-of select="../@name"/></h3>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('plugin_by_report',concat(@pluginID, '|', ../@name))">
                    <xsl:sort select = "@severity" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ReportItem">
    <p>
    Port:<xsl:value-of select="@protocol"/>/<xsl:value-of select="@port"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING! Thank you so much this worked perfectly, hopefully it will be accepted by excel but regardless this is what I wanted. Looks like I really have to lean about Muenchian Grouping. Thanks again!